# Incorrect Model Schema '/V1/orders'

Tags: magento2

I've created a model representing the data returned from the /V1/orders Rest API call. I based it off the data they display in the 'Model Scheme'. When calling the API my model is completely wrong due to fields being returned with underscores between field names.

Am I doing something wrong or have they just inaccurately shown the data.

[image: Model Schema shown on Magento]

[image: Json data returned]

Answer (score 1):

In version 2.1, they updated the documentation to reflect the actual results of the REST call:
http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/

So, to answer your question, this must have been an oversight on their end. This was fixed in this commit: https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/48373c3eea2e54e77275eca0b3dc2ce3a2debddb

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me whether you're answering or asking an new question. Could you clarify what you mean?

Comment: Updated answer and provided more details to the existing answer.

Comment: It looks great! +1.